# Can anyone spot error in Angular code for Codecademy - Calendar App?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to complete the Codecademy project - CalendarApp using AngularJS which using services and routing. For some reason its not running properly. The data isnt being displayed and the expression: {{ day.date | date }} is just showing up as is.

Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong? I have checked other people's examples but can't spot the error.

index.html:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="CalendarApp">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <img src= "img/logo.svg" width="51" height="54">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
       <div ng-view></div>

      <div class="container">


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/DayController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="js/services/events.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('CalendarApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
 .when("/", {
    controller: 'DayController',
   templateUrl: 'views/day.html'
 })
 .when("/:id", {
        controller: 'EventController',
   templateUrl: 'views/event.html'
 })
 .otherwise({
 redirectTo: "/"
 });
});
```

events.js

```
  app.factory('events', ['$http', function($http) {
  return
  $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/events-api/events.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    return data;
  })
  .error(function(err) {
    return err;
  });
}]);
```

DayController.js

```
app.controller('DayController', ['$scope', 'events', function($scope, events) {
     events.success(function(data) {
      $scope.day = data;
     });
    }]);
```

EventController.js

```
   app.controller('EventController', ['$scope', 'events', '$routeParams', function($scope, events, $routeParams) {
  events.success(function(data) {
    $scope.event = data.events[$routeParams.id];
  });
}]);
```

day.html:

```
<h2 class="date"> {{ day.date | date }} </h2>
<div class="event" ng-repeat="event in day.events">
  <a href="#/{{$index}}">
    <h3 class="name">{{ event.name }} </h3>
    <p><span class="from">{{ event.from }}  </span> - <span class="to">{{ event.to }}  </span></p>
  </a>
</div>
```

event.html:

```
<div class="event-detail">
  <h2 class="event-name">{{ event.name }}</h2>
  <p class="time"><span class="from">{{ event.from }}  </span> - <span class="to">{{ event.to }}  </span></p>
  <p class="where">{{ event.where }}  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: check console..there should be some error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular application is showing `{{}}` with content means it has broken somewhere.  I think I know where the problem is.

The problem with your `factory` and `controller`, you returned promise from the `factory` but that `$http` has `.success` & `.error` callback with it. But you can't return the `data` from the callbacks as you are trying in your current code, and once you do `.success` & `.error` on the promise you can't continue that promise chain. Instead I'd suggest you to return the promise from the service then the callback will be attached to it by controller.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('events', ['$http', function($http) {
   return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/events-api/events.json');
}]);
```

By changing your code, your problem will get solved.

Comment: @lauriehocking look at the udpated answer..Thanks :)